# How to make ajax request with Karma

Tags: karma-runner, karma-mocha

I have a test that calls a function which requests an external csv file. But for some reason, I can't use a relative path. For example, I have to do:

```
d3.csv('base/a.csv', ...
```

instead of being able to do :

```
d2.csv('a.csv', ...
```

The second example, works fine on the actual site, but for some reason, since Karma runs in a `base` directory, I have to request it from base. How can I just do a normal relative url?

Here are the parts of my `karma.conf.js` that I customized:

```
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'tests/*.js',
  'bower_components/d3/d3.min.js',
  'game.js',
  {pattern: 'a.csv', watched: false, included: false, served: true}
],
```

and [here is my repo](https://github.com/aharris88/word-up/tree/karma-bug)